# Positioning using the jQuery Validation Engine

Tags: jquery, jquery-validation-engine

I'm using a plugin called jQuery Validation Engine and I'm having real trouble finding any support for me problem.

The engine basically creates a tooltip on my form when a field is left blank. I have it all working correctly, I'm just trying to position it correctly.

[JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KtyyQ/3/) showing form code and inline script, the full JS files and CSS are linked in the JSFiddle

The plugin can be found [here.](http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/) 
The jQuery can be found [here](http://www.jamesperrett.co.uk/testsite/js/jquery.validationEngine.js) (via the site I'm using it on) and also [here](http://www.jamesperrett.co.uk/testsite/js/jquery.validationEngine-en.js).
The CSS file can be found [here](http://www.jamesperrett.co.uk/testsite/css/validationEngine.jquery.css).

The documentation points out that you can position using some preset values (top right, bottom right, top left etc). I'm using topRight.

Essentially I need to work out how to move the positioning slightly. The positioning is working correctly but due to the change on my graphic to have the arrow in the center it doesn't look right.

I'm struggling to find out how the topRight property is set and how I can nudge it by a few pixels to get it to the position I require.

Can anyone who has a bit of a better eye see if they can point me in the right direction?

Comment: Could you perhaps create a jsfiddle that shows a minimal version of your problem? That might make it easier for people to help you/understand what you need.

Comment: Hi, I'll try to put something together. Thing is I know that the positioning will be in one of those files somewhere, I just can't find it, hence why I posted the entire thing because I don't know which bits to omit and which to keep.

Comment: I've added a JS fiddle showing some of the code, but I can't really do the same for the other files because I don't know what to omit, and that is where the solution will be... I just can't find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the tooltip div is controlled  by this class in the css:

(Located in : http://www.position-relative.net/creation/formValidator/css/validationEngine.jquery.css
or  your local equivalent.)

```
.formError .formErrorContent {
    width: 100%;
    background: #ee0101;
    position:relative;
    color: #fff;
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 11px;
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    box-shadow: 0 0 6px #000;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 6px #000;
    padding: 4px 10px 4px 10px;
    border-radius: 6px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
}
```

Overriding the values in this css class with your own should let you do pretty much whatever you would like with the tooltip: color, positioning and the like. For example: Solving your problem with positioning could be done with adding margines in the override (ovveriding selector can be changed if it does not suit your needs):

```
 fieldset .formError .formErrorContent {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
```

This would move the whole tooltip up by 10 pixels.

I hope this is helpfull to your problem!